# can we add extra buttons to iphone native address book view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, addressbook, viewcontroller

I want to know whether we can add extra buttons to iphone native address book view controller ?
For example in contact info view contact in address book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not customize the view controllers of the built-in frameworks unless there is a provision to customize it, like `UImagePickerController` to which you can add a custom `cameraOverlay`.

As for as I know the answer for your question is NO.